# Associating Ribbon Button to a custom list of subsites of a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I have the following site structure:

```
TOP
-- Nodes
---- Node 1
---- Node 2
---- Node 3
................
................
---- Node n
```

All subsites of **Nodes** site **(Node 1, Node 2, ... Node n)** has a custom list: **Node List**

I am trying to add a custom Ribbon Button to the **Node List** of **all** subsites of the site **Nodes**.

When I deploy the following custom action description, I do not see the ribbon button. I am sure I am missing something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <CustomAction Id="NG.Import.ImportAction"
        Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
        Sequence="0"
        Title="Data Import"
        RegistrationId="{$ListId:Lists/Node List;}"
        RegistrationType="List">
  <CommandUIExtension>
   <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
     <Button Id="NG.Import.ImportButton"
         Alt="Data Import"
         Sequence="0"
         LabelText="Data Import"
         Image32by32="_images/NG.Import/excel32.png"
         Image16by16="_images/NG.Import/excel16.png"
         Command="javascript:alert('Hello World!')" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
   </CommandUIDefinitions>
  </CommandUIExtension>
 </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying this as a farm solution? Apparently there is a bug with farm solutions, and the RegistrationId="{$ListId:Lists/Node List;}" syntax only works with sandbox solutions.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/a93cde77-0d3c-4087-aee4-0f5a46aaf636